# VSCode puts Java .class files in src folder

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, src, bin

Whenever I run my `Main.java` file, class files get generated into my `bin` folder *and* to my `src` folder. I've tried configuring the `settings.json` file and setting `"java.project.outputPath"` to `"bin"`. After this, I did Clean Java Language Server Workspace in the Command Palette, but it still didn't work.
Id appreciate all and any help. Thank you.

[image: Picture of bin and src]

[image: settings.json]

Comment: Is there any other process or IDE running that could cause this?

Comment: I'm not sure what else could be running that could cause this.

Comment: Please edit the question by replacing the image of the code with the *code represented as a text* and formatted by enclosing it in triple backticks ``` or with by using the button `{ }`. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

This is specified by the Java language. When you run java files, class files will be automatically generated in the current directory.

```
`"java.project.outputPath": "bin"`  
and
"java.project.sourcePaths": [
    "src"
],
```

in your setting.json means when you use this workspace, the java file in the source paths will be compiled into a class file for you and stored in the output paths.

You could try to delete all .class files and reopen the project. You will find that all class files will be loaded automatically in the bin directory.

Comment: I tried deleting all of the class files in src and bin and I reopened the project, and it still didn't work. I then tried just deleting the class files in src, and then just bin, but that didnt work either

Comment: @mexicanburrito Are you using the tool architecture to build the project? I suggest you using tool to creat project. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project If this still doesn't work, you can submit it as a bug to github.